# Running an Ab initio graph through UNIX

Tags: unix, putty, ab-initio

I'm trying to run an Ab initio graph through UNIX by making use of the air sandbox command.

I'm connecting to a remote server through putty.

I keep getting an 'Air not found' error.

What environment changes do I need to make before I can get the command to work and execute a graph?

Answer (score 2):

To launch graphs using "air sandbox run", you'll need to create an environment variable named AB_HOME whose value is the path where the Ab Initio Co>Operating System has been installed and add $AB_HOME/bin to the front of your user's PATH environment variable. For example, add the following to your user's ~/.profile:

```
export AB_HOME=/usr/local/abinitio
export PATH="$AB_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need more in your profile:

```
AB_HOME=/usr/local/abinitio
export PATH=$AB_HOME/bin:$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export AB_AIR_ROOT=$ABINITIO_ROOT/eme/repo
export AB_ENV_ROOT=<path to:>/sand/stdenv
```

also your user should be in group of "abinitio"