# Testing several data validation graphs developed in Ab Initio environment

Tags: etl, ab-initio

How to test data validation graphs developed in Ab Initio environment ? Can someone explain as am new to this or give links to resources where I can learn more about it ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to documentation https://docs.abinitio.com/ ?

Any Graphs you could run from GDE (Run in menu or F5 hot key) or from shell ([Running an Ab initio graph through UNIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39894625/running-an-ab-initio-graph-through-unix))